# Create a trigger for insert a row if find update a field

Tags: mysql

My target is if find the update to a field the trigger will insert a row to same table with new value.

My Code :

```
DROP TRIGGER `premier`.`create_neworg`;
CREATE TRIGGER `premier`.`create_neworg` AFTER UPDATE
    ON premier.org_infor FOR EACH ROW
IF (NEW.org_customerid IS NOT NUll) THEN
    INSERT INTO premier.org_infor (org_ParentID,org_emcode,org_date,org_contents) VALUES( NEW.org_customerid,OLD.org_emcode,NEW.org_modify,NEW.org_contents);
END IF; 


CREATE TABLE `org_infor` (
  `org_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `org_ParentID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `org_emcode` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `org_customerid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `org_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `org_contents` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_vietnamese_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `org_workingtype` varchar(80) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_vietnamese_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `org_dateend` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `org_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `org_modify` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `org_username` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `org_reasonchange` varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_vietnamese_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `org_infor` (`org_id`, `org_ParentID`, `org_emcode`, `org_customerid`, `org_date`, `org_contents`, `org_workingtype`, `org_dateend`, `org_status`, `org_modify`, `org_username`, `org_reasonchange`) VALUES
(31, '1-10', '4174', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', '3 Ca', NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(32, '1-10', '4185', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', 'Ca1 ,Ca2', NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(34, '1-10', '4513', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(35, '1-10', '4859', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(36, '1-10', '4966', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system1', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(37, '1-10', '4989', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(38, '1-10', '5091', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(39, '1-10', '5100', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(40, '1-10', '5320', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(41, '1-10', '5386', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(42, '1-10', '5405', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(43, '1-10', '5503', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(44, '1-10', '5526', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(45, '1-10', '5759', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(46, '1-10', '5824', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(47, '1-10', '5877', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(48, '1-10', '5895', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(49, '1-10', '5990', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(50, '1-10', '6305', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(51, '1-10', '6579', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(52, '1-10', '6602', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL),
(53, '1-10', '6684', NULL, '2022-11-30', 'Upload from system', NULL, NULL, 0, '2022-11-30 20:21:33', NULL, NULL)
```

but I Tested when update a new value to org_customerid  the system error

Screen error:

[image]

Comment: Please do not forget to add some datasets(org_infor)!

Comment: Yes I have revised thanks.